# For Loop storing output as list to then combine into matrix

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices I would like to first convert into individual vectors then combine them into one large matrix. I have been trying to implement a for loop to do this and have been unable to do so with any success.

Example data: 5 10x10 matrices in a list

```
m1 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
m2 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
m3 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
m4 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
m5 <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
mylist <- list(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
```

I can turn an individual matrix into a vector using the following:

```
unlist(mylist[1])
```

My for loop is as follows, and currently outputs them all into a single vector:

```
z = list()
for (i in mylist[length(mylist)]) {
    n <- unlist(mylist)
    z <- c(n)
} 

length(z)
[1] 500
```

The output I would like would be the df:

```
m1 <- unlist(mylist[1])
m2 <- unlist(mylist[2])
m3 <- unlist(mylist[3])
m4 <- unlist(mylist[4])
m5 <- unlist(mylist[5])
df <- cbind(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5)
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You just want to convert each matrix to a vector? `z = lapply(mylist, c)`? (FYI, your `for` loop isn't working because you probably want `z[[i]] <- c(n)`, but the `lapply` is nicer.)

Comment: I updated my question to show what I'd like my output to be, thanks Gregor!

Comment: In your desired output, are you sure you want `m1 <- unlist(mylist[m1])`, not `m1 <- unlist(mylist[1])`? (And maybe it would make sense to call it something new, say `n1` instead of the `m1` you already used?)

Comment: That was a typo, I meant to put `m1 <- unlist(mylist[1])`  I'll edit that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a for loop, I would do it like this:

```
z = list()
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
    z[[i]] = c(mylist[[i]])
}
```

But when you're just applying a simple function to each list element, `lapply` is very nice:

```
z = lapply(mylist, c)
```

If you then want to `cbind` all of these vectors, we can either use `Reduce` or `do.call`:

```
do.call(what = cbind, args = z)
Reduce(f = cbind, x = z)
```

The `do.call` is equivalent to `cbind(z[[1]], z[[2]], z[[3]], ...)`, and the `Reduce` is equivalent to `cbind(z[[1]], cbind(z[[2]], cbind(z[[3]], ...)))`. Since `cbind` accepts any number of arguments, `do.call` is probably nicer. You would need `Reduce` if you wanted to add or multiply the vectors, for example.